# Как сделать подобный border?

Tags: css

Всем привет. Нашел сайт с красивым бордером, но не понимаю, как его сделать. Думал через псевдоэлементы, но как сделать, чтобы он был фиксированной ширины?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите да посмотрите как он там сделан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
div {
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  outline: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  outline-offset: -15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :)